# Can a core bridge on Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Server be configured between the same source and destination server

Tags: bridge, activemq-artemis

I am trying to understand if a core bridge on Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Server be configured between the same source and destination server. The reason why I'm doing this is because my publishers write messages to Queue A and Queue B but my subscriber only listens to Queue AB. So my intent is to bridge Queues A and B into Queue AB. From Artemis [user manual](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/core-bridges.html) I read :

> The function of a bridge is to consume messages from a source queue, and forward them to a target address, typically on a different Apache ActiveMQ Artemis server

and

> In summary, bridges are a way to reliably connect two separate Apache ActiveMQ Artemis servers together. With a core bridge both source and target servers must be Apache ActiveMQ Artemis servers.

What isn't clear to me is if the source and the destination Artemis server could be the same or do they need to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking I don't see why a core bridge can't have the same source and destination broker. However, it's not necessary. You can simply use a [divert](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/diverts.html) for your use-case. As the documentation states:

> Diverts allow you to transparently divert messages routed to one address to some other address, without making any changes to any client application logic.

Comment: Would it be possible for the address that the messages that have been diverted to act as a source for another address? If this is possible, Would the new destination address can be have a different routing type than the source, In other words, MY new source address is a multicast and the new destination is an anycast and If I understand this right, diverts between address with different routing types isn't possible from what I read [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/diverts.html).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by an address which is the target of a divert being the "source" for another address. Could you ask this in a new question so I can ask clarifying questions, etc? The comments section really isn't the place for such a discussion, especially since the root question has already been answered. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I perhaps can add a diagram as well, so its more clearer.